# Mysql - select with condition and input in array?

Tags: mysql, radix, rule

I have table like this

```
|  idrule  |  idsys  |
----------------------
|R01#1     |     1   |
|R01#1     |     2   |
|R01#2     |     1   |
|R01#2     |     3   |
|R01#2     |     4   |
|R01#3     |     2   |
|R01#3     |     1   |
|R01#3     |     5   |
|R01#4     |     1   |
|R01#4     |     4   |
|R01#4     |     3   |
----------------------
```

I want to select with 2 condition in one input array, if I want to input (idsys = 1 and idsys = 2) so the output should be:

```
| idrule |
----------
|R01#1   |
|R01#3   |
----------
```

there anyone can help? thanks

-----QUESTION ADDITION-----
 this is the solution:

```
SELECT idrule
FROM tablename
WHERE idsys IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY idrule
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

I want to add in "Where" condition "MAX(somefield)"  it is available? so the code will be :

```
SELECT idrule
FROM tablename
WHERE MAX(somefiled) and
idsys IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY idrule
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

but not working? any Idea?

Comment: When asking a question, you should let us know what you've already tried and what went wrong. You should also try to include all relevant information. In this case, we would need to know the table name to write the query for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT idrule
FROM tablename
WHERE idsys IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY idrule
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you Jhon, I will try.

Comment: @Jhon, thank you, the answer is right. that's I mean, btw I want to ask Jhon, what is the meaning of HAVING count(*) = 2?...it is the length of the input (idsys IN(1,2))  ?

Comment: Yes. If you run `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE idsys IN (1, 2)`, it will show all the idrules having idsys 1 or 2. You only need to select those idrules the number of entries is equal to the length of the set (1, 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT idrule 
    FROM *table* t 
        JOIN *table* ct ON t.idrule = ct.idrule 
    WHERE t.idsys=1 AND ct.idsys=2;
```